# Why is my trigger not working on my Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a SQL/PSM trigger that I have to apply to my Oracle database but it won't work and I really don't understand why...

Here is my trigger for MySQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_ACTIVITE_COMPL"
BEFORE INSERT ON "ACTIVITE_COMPL"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT "auto_ACTIVITE_COMPL".nextval INTO :NEW."AC_NUM" 
    FROM dual;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_RAPPORT_VISITE"
BEFORE INSERT ON "RAPPORT_VISITE" 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT "auto_RAPPORT_VISITE".nextval INTO :NEW."RAP_NUM" 
    FROM dual;
END;
```

Here is my trigger for Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "trigger_ACTIVITE_COMPL" 
BEFORE INSERT ON "ACTIVITE_COMPL" 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT "auto_ACTIVITE_COMPL".nextval 
    INTO :NEW."AC_NUM" 
    FROM dual;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "trigger_RAPPORT_VISITE" 
BEFORE INSERT ON "RAPPORT_VISITE" 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT "auto_RAPPORT_VISITE".nextval 
    INTO :NEW."RAP_NUM" 
    FROM dual;
END;
```

When I execute this statement, the console says:

> [Warning, Error code 17 110, SQLState 99999] Warning: exécution
>   terminée avec avertissement
>
> [1:1] Executed successfully in 0,318 s. no rows affected.
>
> [8:1] Failed in 0 s. 
>   [Exception, Error code 900, SQLState 42000]
>   ORA-00900: instruction SQL non valide
>
> Line 8, column 1
>
> [Warning, Error code 17 110, SQLState 99999] Warning: exécution
>   terminée avec avertissement
>
> [10:1] Executed successfully in 0,037 s. no rows affected.
>
> [17:1] Failed in 0 s. 
>   [Exception, Error code 900, SQLState 42000]
>   ORA-00900: instruction SQL non valide
>
> Line 17, column 1
>
> Execution finished after 0,445 s, 2 errors occurred.

So from why I understand there's a syntax error but I can't find what's wrong, I just know the error is located at the lines 5 & 13 because when I execute `SQL SELECT "auto_ACTIVITE_COMPL".nextval FROM dual;`, it does work.

I don't think you need the database structure to idetify the problem since it's clearly a syntax error but I don't know what is exactly.

Please help me if you have an idea what the issue is.

Thank you.

PS: I am not really good in PL/SQL and especially when it comes to Oracle so be kind and sorry if I sound ignorant (it's because I am lmao).

Comment: Have you tried to end the trigger code with `/` ?  After `END;` in next line put `/` and try

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, actually my script did contain `/` at first but it didn't work and I had 4 errors instead of 2 errors without them... So I removed them and I really don't know what else I can do, does my script look correct to you?

Comment: Yes, It seems fine. Are you able to create the single trigger ? and in which client you are trying to compile the trigger?

Comment: I am using Netbeans and I'm connected to the database as a c##user.
The single line `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER...` is apparently executed but the rest doesn't work and shows an error.

Comment: As a side comment, when you create an object by specifying its name enclosed in double-quotes, it's name is preserved in the data dictionary in exactly the case that you specified.  So when you reference it in the future, you must also enclose the reference in double-quotes and specify in exactly the same (mixed)case that you created it.  Not a good thing.  Best practice for oracle - _never_ enclose an object name in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a select statement for what you're doing. Try this:

```
 :NEW."AC_NUM" := "auto_ACTIVITE_COMPL".nextval;
```

Also, what @EdStevens said above: best practice is to never enclose object names in double quotes!

```
 :NEW.AC_NUM := auto_ACTIVITE_COMPL.nextval;
```